# How do you properly set up a Golang library?

Tags: go

I've tried many times to set up a REAL go package with the modules system and store code in `pkg`. [All the tutorials I've found are too basic](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module), creating a module with go files stores at the top level, and I keep getting `no Go files in /usr/local/go/github.com/me/mypackage`.

I've tried a bunch of different things, but I can't get it to work properly...

`GOROOT` is set to `/usr/local/go`. I created a package here `/usr/local/go/github.com/me/mypackage`.

`go.mod`

```
module github.com/me/mypackage

go 1.18
```

`pkg/main.go`

```
package mypackage

// Add is our function that sums two integers
func Add(x, y int) (res int) {
    return x + y
}

// Subtract subtracts two integers
func Subtract(x, y int) (res int) {
    return x - y
}
```

`pkg/main_test.go`

```
package mypackage

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T){

    got := Add(4, 6)
    want := 10

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %q, wanted %q", got, want)
    }
}
```

And I run: `go test`

What am I doing wrong? I find Go so frustrating to set up because languages/runtimes like Rust and NodeJS have very friendly package managers and are real easy to setup.

I'm trying to structure a library as described in [this guidance for structuring go packages](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout).

Comment: you need a package main

Comment: Follow the tutorial.  Put the code under your home directory, not GOROOT.  Put the code in the same directory as go.mod, not in a pkg subdirectory.  Also, try this tutorial: https://go.dev/doc/code.  I think it’s easier to follow than the on linked in the question.

Comment: Adding a `package main` file at the top level enables go commands to run, but doesn't actually pick up the tests. @Dan And I did see that tutorial, but it still stores the code at the top-level, which is not what I desired. @Zombo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse modules with packages.
One module might hold many packages.
Like this:

- module_dir/package1_dir
- module_dir/package2_dir

Try this layout:

Repository: github.com/me/mymodule

```
mymodule/mypkg
mymodule/mypkg/mypkg_test.go
mymodule/mypkg/mypkg.go
mymodule/go.mod
```

In `mypkg.go` and `mypkg_test.go` declare `package mypkg`.

Otherwise, run this script and it will create a correct layout for you:

https://gist.github.com/udhos/695d3be51fb4c7d151b4e252cdec3c63

Comment: Ah, tx for clarifying the package vs. module issue. Once I did as you recommend, I still got the same error. However, in the gist you sent, `go test -v ./...` worked whereas simply `go test` failed. I created `mymodule/pkg/mypkg`, which is what I was trying to do, so now it works and is structured as desired.